# Word VBA Compile Error

Tags: vba, ms-word, user-profile

I have a word document that has a few userforms and options to auto create an entire document. It works great on all of the installations I have tried from 2007 to 2013. The problem is that one user on one computer gets compile errors when it the user form is launched. The compiler complains that controls do not exist that actually DO IN FACT exist. I had him create a temporary account, just a simple test account, no admin permissions and it runs fine.

I have have tried killing the usual suspects
-.dotm files
- normal.dot files
- wiped word start up folders
- I have reset the word registry key
- I have renamed the appdata\Microsoft\office, appdata\Microsoft\word etc etc etc.

There are no missing references.

More oddities:
it complains about a missing control, lets just say frm.txtname.
I cut the sub that contains the reference and paste it at the bottom POOF it no longer believes the control is missing but...it finds another one to complain about.

I know it is something wonked up in the profile but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: In VBA editor open Tool bar and click References. You will see the list of references. Unclick those who starts with "MISSING". It should work.

Comment: I really wish I understood exactly what makes that happen to begin with.

Comment: It is happening while users save MS file with VBA macro on their hard drive. It happens all the time with my Excel Tools. I will work on the solution and post it in here if found one. If anyone already know the way to prevent this problem, please post it here.

Comment: I know opening the file in different versions of office can cause it.

Comment: Not in my case. All users have the same version.